# Open new webpage using js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl

i have a website that has a login form and i want it to use AJAX and PHP, the AJAX and php scripts work file, well most of it, but when i try and redirect to a new page i have a problem.

The problem is i am using

```
document.getElementById("signup_form").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

to update the signup_form div, so if something went wrong i can write it to the one part of the web page. However when the login details are correct it loads the new page in side this small div in the top right of my website.....

In my PHP script if the login details are correct i use location to redirect and i have also tried it with cURL, but frankly i'm not sure how to go about this.

I want the whole page to change from www.something.com to www.something.com/members instead of it loading into a give on the www.something.com page. Also i am storing session data so i don't want to lose this when going to a new page.

Any help and tutorials would be more than welcome, i am in the process of learning js and AJAX.

thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AJAX you cannot and you should not redirect from server side/php side using header location. Instead use

```
window.location
```

property of javascript for this after you receive succesful response. Something like this

```
window.location = "www.something.com/members";
```

Comment: Why shouldn't i redirect from server side?

Comment: Becuase you are making an ajax call and your ajax call is waiting for the response. And it will never complete process if you don't return the response.

Comment: I've got most of it working but i set the session Variables with PHP and it seems to get rid of them, so my members page will check session to see if the user is active, if not logs out... Its all set to active but when it forwards to the new page the session checking script sends me back to the login page. Would the js be destroying the session or is a new sessions being created when i'm redirected?

Comment: I don't think so if session is there it should not redirect you, may be you need to put session_start on the starting of the page. Just check is session getting set or not. You can go to members page and echo your session and exit before the code where it redirect back to login page if you are not logged in.

Comment: You were right, i had the session start in the php file that originally called the log in script (The old way) but needed to add session_start before added the session data in the login method. Thats a bunch for your help, it's all working now (But it's a bit of a mess, think it's gonnna be a rewrite for the login system soon).